# Enumerating all the crystallographic directions over a half sphere in a crystal

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

Im taking alook at this paper [1] where there is the following statement:

> CO2 was treated as a linear rigid molecule and energies were computed for 61 orientations at each center-of-mass position. These consisted of all the <100>, <110>, <111>, <321>, <2.414 1 0>, and <2.732 1 1> directions over the half-sphere. The results plotted in Fig. 2 represent the minimum energies over these 61 orientations, for each center-of-mass position.

I understand the directions. However, how does the 61 samples end up being all the directions over the half sphere? Secondly, How would you enumerate them?

[1] [PrB](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.085410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to consider the full sphere first. It is all about finding all the permutations of index and sign allowed by each family of directions.

<100> has 6 possibilities, with a 1 or -1 on any of the 3 axes

<110> has 12 possibilities, with a (1,1) (1,-1) (-1,1) (-1,-1) permuted across 3 axes

<111> has 8 possibilities, all the various signs

<321> has 24 possibilities, permuting the numbers and changing signs

<2.414 1 0> has 24 possibilities, 6 permutations and 4 sign flips

<2.732 1 1> has 48 possibilities, 6 permutations and 8 sign flips

The total for the full sphere is 122 directions, so 61 for a half sphere.

Comment: great!, could you ellaborate on the last two? the 4 sign flips and 8 sign flips?

Comment: if possible, maybe comment on why those directions would be the ones for the linear molecule

Comment: Each of the non-zero numbers can be either plus or minus. So, <2.414 1 0> has only 4 sign-flip permutations, since 0 = -0. <2.732 1 1> has 2$^{3}$ sign permutations.

Comment: As for the specific directions being of interest, I think one would have to look at specifics of the voids in the metal organic framework to see where a linear molecule of a certain dimension (like CO2) might fit. I'm not an expert on MOFs, and one might want a structure imaging program of some type. Just not my field...